# R: filter() in for loop running through columns

Tags: r, filter, apply, tidyverse

in R - trying to loop through a list of column names, filtering by a specific entry and counting the number of occurrences of that entry. I'm trying to run something like what's below in a pipe within the for loop to do this - but I can't get what's below to work unless I substitute `questionNumbers[i]` for a direct column name.

```
df %>%
nrow(filter(questionNumbers[i] == Response[1])) %>%
....etc
```

Any ideas? I have a feeling there's an `apply()` way to do this - thoughts?

Comment: You're correct in your intuition that an `apply` family function would work. `lapply(df, function(x) sum(x == df$Response[1]))` will tell you how many elements in each column equal `df$Response[1]`

Comment: @RyanD - thanks - my hang up though is trying to do that for only specific columns... how do I augment apply() to do that?

Comment: You can replace `df` with `df[, c('column1', 'column2')]` where `'column1'` and `'column2'` are the names of the columns you want to check. So `lapply(df[, column_name_vector], function(x) sum(x == df$Response[1]))`

Comment: It might help if you add a reproducible example, either with part of your own data, or show us how this calculation might look on an example dataset

Answer (score 0):

so assuming that you have a `data.frame` (I'll play with `mtcars`) and a vector of results (`c(1,2)`) that you're looking for. The following mixture of `lapply` will work with the `tibble`, and `tidyr` packages.

```
responses = c(1,2)

#create a named list
exampleOutput <- lapply(setNames(names(mtcars),names(mtcars)), function(x){
  lapply(setNames(responses, paste0('response_', responses)),function(y){
    mtcars[mtcars[x] == y, x] %>%
      length
  }) %>% 
    #convert named list into a tibble/dataframe
    tibble::as.tibble()
}) %>%
  #convert list into a tibble/dataframe
  tibble::enframe() %>%
  #open up the nested data
  tidyr::unnest()
```

you'll get something like this

```
  name  response_1 response_2
   <chr>      <int>      <int>
 1 mpg            0          0
 2 cyl            0          0
 3 disp           0          0
 4 hp             0          0
 5 drat           0          0
 6 wt             0          0
 7 qsec           0          0
 8 vs            14          0
 9 am            13          0
10 gear           0          0
11 carb           7         10
```